# Rails - Bootstrap and AJAX Calls

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

So, i have an app, it uses RoR 4.2.0 and Ruby 2.2.0.  This is an online store, that has a store with products, with an 'Add to cart' button, that i have setup to use remote calls to add the products to the cart.  The cart has also a button that with a remote call destroys the current cart.

This used to work well on Rails 4.1.x, but after i upgraded my app to 4.2.0 (and changed all the other gems to latest versions) it doesn't.  The problem is, it sends 2 calls in every remote call, instead of one (at some point it sent three as well, i didn't realize when it happened as i've tinkered with other places in the codebase as well), resulting in having two items added on click to the Add to cart button, and two prompts for deletion on Destroy cart click.

What i have tried to solve this, is i changed the position of entries in application.js as stated in another question.  This is my current application.js:

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui/effect-blind
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require analytics
//= require blueimp-gallery-all
```

If i leave this the way it is now, Bootstrap navbar menu works (why? bootstrap needs jQuery, ain't that right?) but i have the problem stated above.  If i move Bootstrap below jquery, AJAX calls work as they should, but i have no Bootstrap menu.  Weird part is, if i DELETE the whole jquery line, everything works as it should.  What is going on here?  Did bootstrap started including jQuery at some point?  Or is my asset pipeline "damaged" somehow?  I have cleared temp and assets (rake tmp:clear && rake assets:clean).

EDIT: Removing jquery from javascript.js does not work in production but works in development.  I'm seriously confused.

Comment: Did you call `javascript_include_tag "application"` twice?

Comment: What `bootstrap gem` do you use?
If you use [this gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails). Then you should follow this guideline from [here](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#using-javascript)

Comment: I use 'bootstrap-sass' and javascript_include_tag is called once.

Comment: Removing jquery from javascript.js does not work in production but works in development. I'm seriously confused.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue.

**The reason was:**

1. **Multiple inclusion** of `application.js` (layout + custom_view file) due to which there were three calls for single click.
2. just include jQuery and `jquery-us.js` in `application.js` and remove other js/jquery versions and then check again
3. use `"data-turbolinks-track" => true` such as

   ```
   <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>        
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>**
   ```

Hope this might resolve your issue.

Comment: `"data-turbolinks-track" => true` is enabled, and i dont' include jquery in any other file.  I will test leaving only `jquery` and `jquery-ujs`when i go home.  I believe that either something in my `config/environments/development.rb` messes with my assets, or one of these libraries includes `jquery` as well.

Comment: So, i finally figured this out... Apparently, i had assets precompiled for production, that stood in the way of my app working correctly... I run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean`, then i corrected the `application.js` to have the correct row (first `jquery`, then `bootstrap`) and finally i run RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile, i uploaded to heroku and all is well... Sorry for disturbing all of you, and thnx for the answers, i never saw this anywhere (so i thought that precompiling would just overwrite the old ones) so it was seer luck that led me to the solution.